# Proper notation for motion integration

Tags: integration, notation

Say you have a projectile where at $t=0$, $ v = 0 $ and $ x = 0 $.

Given $ \ddot x = -4$, in order to find $ \dot x $, we must integrate $ \frac{dv}{dt} $ as follows:

$$ \frac{dv}{dt} = -4 \Rightarrow dv = -4dt $$

$$ \int_{0}^{v} dv = \int_{0}^{t} -4 dt $$

$$ \therefore v = -4t $$

The question I have regard the bounds in the integration. I feel that it isn't proper to have the same variable in the bound and integration (i.e. $ O \rightarrow v $ when integrating in respect to $dv$).

Is this incorrect? If so, what is the correct way of attempting such questions other than adding the constant of integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all rigor, you should use distinct names for the dummy variables

$$ \int_{\nu=0}^{v} d\nu = \int_{\tau=0}^{t} -4 d\tau ,$$

then

$$ \nu\bigg|_{\nu=0}^{v} = -4\tau\bigg|_{\tau=0}^{t}.$$